# How to calculate the previous week values and MTD when the dates are not consistent in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have input a file that has Patch name, date, available, and patched as columns.

[image: Input file]

I want to create a table with two columns, where one column displays the `score(patched/Available)` as of MTD while the other column displays the `score as of last week`, that is, what was the score last week when the file was refreshed.

[image: Expected output]

So, for the week starting today(19/07/21), it will show the data from `12/07/21-18/07/21`. But since there are not any values present for the given dates, it will show `NA` as values.

For creating the `Score` I used MTD, whereas for the `Score as of last week`, I'm unable to create a DAX.

Thank you.

Edit:- Column `Due Date US` can be used as a date column. All the date columns also have years in them.

Comment: Which one is your date column? Date without Year value is not a good format. If you have appropriate date column, you can then create the Week value per row which may help you to calculate the previous week's value.

Comment: You can use any of the Due Date Columns as date columns. These date columns also have the year values, which I forgot to add here. I want to add only the previous week from today's value. Can you please explain the method you are talking about. Thanks.

Comment: If its always previous week considering Today, you can generate the start and end date of last week using DAX. then calculate your value using BETWEEN method in DAX.